# Removing duplicates in a C array

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, logic

I am writing a program which determines the intersection of 2 integer arrays (size of 10 elements). I think I got every other parts covered except for sorting out duplicates. Does anyone know a way of checking duplicates without making a function or using an external C library?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10

int main(void){
    //Initialization
    int array1[SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("Input integer %d of set A: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &array1[i]);
    }

    int array2[SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("Input integer %d of set B: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &array2[i]);
    }

    int intersection[SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        intersection[i] = '\0';
    }

    //Intersection check
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            if (array1[i] == array2[j])
            {
                intersection[i] = array1[i];
                break;
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    //duplicate check

    int count = SIZE;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < count; j++)
        {
            if (intersection[i] == intersection[j])
            {
                for (int k = j; j < count; i++)
                {
                    intersection[k] = intersection[k + 1];
                }

                count--;
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    //printing set
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE ; i++)
    {
        //printf("%d\n", intersection[i]);
        if (intersection[i] != '\0')
        {
            printf("%d\n", intersection[i]);
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

In the code above i was trying one method although it didn't work and instead made the program stuck after inputting all the elements. I am open to other methods as long it doesn't require an external library to run. Thanks

Comment: Did you try to debug this?

Comment: If the code doesn't initially work as expected it isn't necessarily a reason to immediately go looking for a different solution. At least try to debug the code. Use a debugger to step thru your code to find out where things go wrong in your duplicate removal code.

Comment: _without making a function_: what's wrong with that?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I just started university and am on week 3 which they haven't taught us functions, while it may be easier using a custom function, I would like to stay within the parameters of my school's pace.

Comment: no ihavent tried debugging it, what debugger do you recommend to be used in VSCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i see it now , in the third loop where you checking your duplicates i thing that you have to  increese k not i :
for (int k = j; j < count; k++), also you must decrise the size of j in your code under the count--;.So your code for checking duplicates seems right but , you want  the intersection of this two arrays you made , so you dont have to check for duplicates because in the array intersection[SIZE] you will put only one number from the two arrays, so you will not have duplicates .You should check for duplicates if you wanted to make the union of this two arrays .I make some changings to your code acording what you want to create and this code here find the intersection from two arrays.Try this  and delete the duplicate check because that makes your code to run to infinity . One last thing your intersection check must be replace whith this :

//Intersection check

```
int i = 0, j = 0,k=0; // k is for the intersection array !

while (i < SIZE && j < SIZE) { 
    if (array1[i] < array2[j]) 
        i++; 
    else if (array2[j] < array1[i]) 
        j++; 
    else if(array1[i]==array2[j]) // if array1[i] == array2[j]
    { 
       
       
        intersection[k]=array2[j];
        //printf("intersection[%d]=%d\n",i,intersection[i]);
        intersectCount++;
        k++;
        i++; 
        j++;
    } 
} 
printf("intersectCount=%d\n",intersectCount);
```